# How to \expandafter a \let#1 in macro definition

Tags: tex-core

Sometimes, I want to redefine some ***cs*** in a range, generally a macro definition. Like:

```
\def [[csname>]] {

    [[Redefine some cs]]

    [[Actual function of this macro]]

    [[Recover the redefined cs]]

}
```

What mainly needed to do is define macros of `Redefine` and `Recover`, let's call them `\redefine` and `\recover`.

For recovering, a hardly conflict ***cs*** should be used to store the meaning of ***cs*** to be redefined, and their names should be relative. Here I use "the csname of its csname" :

```
\def\redefine#1#2{
    \expandafter \let \csname\string#1\endcsname #1 \relax
    \def#1{#2}
}
```

Where `#1` is the ***cs*** to be redefined.

Now I found that the original meaning can not be recover.

```
\def\recover#1{
    \let #1 \csname\string#1\endcsname
}
```

<del>It seems that `\csname\string#1\endcsname` can not be expanded before `\let`， because `#` `1` are two different tokens but treated as argument replacement in macro definition iff they successively appear. Meanwhile `\expandafter` just skip 1 token.</del>

Maybe `\def` but not `\let` can be used in most cases, I still want to know any way to make the 2nd token be expanded before the 1st when the 1st token is an argument?

---

i.e.

Some shorter primitive cs are defined:

```
\let\epaf\expandafter
\let\str\string
\let\nep\noexpand
\let\cs\csname
\let\sc\endcsname
...
```

for a macro named `\mfont` that parse a sentence until `\relax`, and set lots of font attribute, and make a single cs set latin font and unicode font at the same time. It use lots of primitive cs to parse sentence, definiiton is hard to read if keep the long name.

After a block from `\mfont` to `\relax` , shoter names should be recovered. `\mfont` should define font for global but the shorter names should be valid just in the `\mfont` range.

Comment: Can't you just use grouping? I mean: `\begingroup` ... `\def\cs{whatever}` ... `\endgroup`?

Comment: You have abstracted the question well, but IMHO if you posit the question in context with a real-world application, you might get better answers and methods of achieving what you want. [(x-y problem)](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Some rare circumstances I want to define the "top" macro for global but "internal" macros in group, and the "internal" macros can‘t be expand immediately. Should I just forgive such complex structure and redesign document format ? @Rmano

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is still not very clear. It still looks like what you are saying can be achieved with grouping.

Comment: Try this:

\def\bar{foo}
\def\foo#1{\begingroup\def\bar{#1}\endgroup}\foo{bar}\bar\par
\def\foo#1{\begingroup\gdef\bar{#1}\endgroup}\foo{bar}\bar
\bye

Comment: Ah, but if you `\global\def`, then grouping does not work, clearly. But you didn't mention it in the question... 

Comment: @Rmano yes, that's what I wanted to show them that they can create a global macro from inside a group. Their latest comment expresses the need for what they call the "top macro" to be global.

Comment: Maybe `\def\foo#1{%
    \begingroup
    \let\savedbar\bar
    \gdef\bar{#1}%
    Using new {\tt \string\bar}: \bar
    \global\let\bar\savedbar
    \endgroup
}`  so that the `\savedbar` is anyway local (no need to create a strange name?)

Comment: @Rmano but in this situation why would we even need grouping and `\global`? The following has the same effect as in your code: `\def\bar{foo}\bar\par
\def\foo#1{%
  \let\savedbar\bar
  \def\bar{#1}%
  Using new {\tt\string\bar}: \bar
  \let\bar\savedbar
}
\foo{foobar}\par
\bar
\bye`

Comment: your `\recover` does `\let #1 \csname`  so defines `#1` to be `\csname` other than that it is very hard to comment as you only post disconnected fragments and no examples

Comment: `\def\redefine#1#2 {` _requires_ a space after `#2` similarly `\def\recover#1 {` defines `\recover` with a space delimited argument

Comment: @Niranjan because if there is a `\savedbar` in your document defined before, my code will not change it (at leat not outside the group).

Comment: @Rmano Ah! Makes sense, thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You had spurious spaces, and missing `\expandafter`

```
% no space!!!!
\def\redefine#1#2{%
    \expandafter \let \csname\string#1\endcsname #1%
    \def#1{#2}%
}




% no space!!!!
\def\recover#1{%
% missing \expandafter 
    \expandafter \let \expandafter #1\csname\string#1\endcsname
}


{\tt \string\sin=\meaning\sin}

\redefine\sin{hello}

{\tt \string\sin=\meaning\sin}

\recover\sin

{\tt \string\sin=\meaning\sin}

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I just don't aware that ```\expandafter``` can work exactly next to another ```\expandafter```. And I tried ```\def\stringstring#1{\expandafter\string\csname\string#1\endcsname}
\def\cscs#1{\expandafter\if\stringstring#1\else#1\fi}
```, this can make ```\expandafter\let\csname\cscs#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname\string#1\endcsname``` works.

Comment: @rikuri the `\expandafter` in `\cscs` is doing nothing there

Comment: Yes, according to texbook ```\if``` will totally expand conditions, thanks for comment!

Answer (score 3):

Besides spurious spaces, your code for `\recover` does

```
\let #1 \csname\string#1\endcsname
```

If you call `\recover\foo` you get

```
\let\foo\csname\string\foo\endcsname
```

so you are redefining `\foo` to be `\csname`, printing `\foo` (as a string) and get an error message about a badly placed `\endcsname`.

You need

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname\string#1\endcsname
```

so the token is formed *before* `\let` starts to act.

Alternative method where you need not worry about spurious spaces and `\expandafter`.

The `c` argument type means “form a control sequence token” (it uses `\csname...\endcsname` internally and applies the correct `\expandafter` sequence. Also `\cs_set:Npn` is the equivalent of `\def` (actually `\long\def`, but it's unimportant in this context).

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \redefine #1 #2
 {
  % save the current meaning of #1
  \cs_set_eq:cN { \token_to_str:N #1 } #1
  \cs_set:Npn #1 { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \recover #1
 {
  \cs_set_eq:Nc #1 { \token_to_str:N #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

{\tt \string\sin=\meaning\sin}

\redefine\sin{hello}

{\tt \string\sin=\meaning\sin}

\recover\sin

{\tt \string\sin=\meaning\sin}

\bye
```

[image]

If you don't want to go this route, you can and should define your own syntactic sugar. But `expl3` offers you *much* more than `\cs_set_eq:NN` and variants thereof.

```
\def\cslet#1{\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\letcs#1#2{\expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname#2\endcsname}

\def\redefine#1#2{%
  % save the current meaning of #1
  \cslet{\string#1}#1%
  % redefine #1
  \def#1{#2}%
}
\def\recover#1{\letcs#1{\string#1}}

{\tt \string\sin=\meaning\sin}

\redefine\sin{hello}

{\tt \string\sin=\meaning\sin}

\recover\sin

{\tt \string\sin=\meaning\sin}

\bye
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of coping with implicit space when doing `\let` I suggest s.th. like this:

```tex
\def\redefine#1{%
  \expandafter\futurelet\csname\string#1\endcsname\def#1%
}%
\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
\def\recover#1{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname\string#1\endcsname}{\let#1= }%
}%

\def\foobar{foo}
\foobar

\redefine\foobar{bar}
\foobar

\recover\foobar
\foobar

\bigskip
Doing the implicit space game:
\bigskip

\exchange{ }{\let\foobar= }%
A\foobar A

\redefine\foobar{bar}
B\foobar B

\recover\foobar
C\foobar C

\bye
```

[image]

Alternatively just do some scoping via `\begingroup..\endgroup` or `{..}`:

```tex
\def\foobar{foo}%
\foobar

\begingroup
\def\foobar{bar}%
\foobar
\endgroup

\foobar

{%
\def\foobar{bar}%
\foobar
}%

\foobar

\bye
```